# WinRT - Programmatically tab to next control in C# code behind

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, code-behind

Once I successfully validate user data in a TextBox (using TextChanged EventHandler), I'd like to programmatically tab to the next input control.  I know I could hard code the name and do

```
Score2.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Keyboard);
```

but I've got 20 TextBox controls on the page page and I'd like to use the same EventHandler for all of them.

Answer (score -1):

While it may be possible (iterate through the page's control inspecting their tab order and selecting the appopriate next control), I would recommend against it. It will irritate your user if they leave a text box to go back and correct a previous field but your app decides it knows better and gives focus to another field.